# Transfer using linux ssh and maintaining permissions

Tags: ssh, rsync, tar

I need to transfer files across ssh to another server. The file structures are identical on both sides. I have used scp -r but that does not retain the orginal file/dir permissions. rsync does the job of keeping the permissions in tact but does not delete the files on the destination side if I want to overwrite them because of changes. I know rsync will write the changes when the source files are newer but I need it to just copy everything reguardless of the date (ie replace destination directory with the one I am moving) without having to shell into the destination first and manually delete the dir.

I heard tar can do this but I can not seem to get it to work without errors. The syntax is

```
tar -cf - /directory/directory | ssh host.name tar -xf - C /destination_directory
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

rsync can delete files on the destination using the --delete syntax.  If you want it to overwrite a file in it's entirety versus it's partial sync implementation, try --whole-file.

Excerpts from http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html:

> -W, --whole-file
>       With this option rsync's delta-transfer algorithm is not used
>   and the whole file is sent as-is
>   instead. The transfer may be faster if
>   this option is used when the bandwidth
>   between the source and destination
>   machines is higher than the bandwidth
>   to disk (especially when the "disk" is
>   actually a networked filesystem). This
>   is the default when both the source
>   and destination are specified as local
>   paths, but only if no batch-writing
>   option is in effect.
>
> --delete
>       This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving
>   side (ones that aren't on the sending
>   side), but only for the directories
>   that are being synchronized. You must
>   have asked rsync to send the whole
>   directory (e.g. "dir" or "dir/")
>   without using a wildcard for the
>   directory's contents (e.g. "dir/*")
>   since the wildcard is expanded by the
>   shell and rsync thus gets a request to
>   transfer individual files, not the
>   files' parent directory. Files that
>   are excluded from the transfer are
>   also excluded from being deleted
>   unless you use the --delete-excluded
>   option or mark the rules as only
>   matching on the sending side (see the
>   include/exclude modifiers in the
>   FILTER RULES section).

Answer (score 0):

As Eddie pointed out, `rsync --delete -Ha` will do the job for you.  Make sure to use the `--dry-run`/`-n` option before you actually run it to avoid accidentally deleting everything in the wrong directory.  Rsync interprets your directories differently depending on whether you append a trailing slash (see [`man rsync`](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) and search for "trailing"), so it's easy to get things wrong if you're not paying attention.

I also use tar sometimes like you're doing.  I think you're simply missing a dash before the `C` in your command above.  As a rule of thumb, you can only omit the dashes in the first parameter.  (But you could also use `cd` instead of the awkward `-C` syntax.)  With the `tar` on your source side you're creating a extra leading `directory/` in the path names in your archive, so I'd `cd` first on the source side as well.  The `-f -` is redundant by the way (tar uses stdin/stdout by default).  So here's what my piped tars tend to look like:

```
cd /some/dir; tar c my_dir | ssh host 'cd /the/target/dir; rm -rf my_dir; tar x'
```

Use `sudo tar` on the host side to preserve ownership when extracting.  (Tip: Use `cz`/`xz` instead of `c`/`x` for gzipped transfer, or pipe through `lzop` and `lzop -d` for real-time compression if you're transferring over Ethernet cable.)